# How can I remove partitions? I already have 4

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

Help I want to remove my partitions everything apart from my windows 7 how can I do this ?
http://fpaste.org/159716/07549141/

Answer (score 2):

Both Windows and Ubuntu provide graphical interfaces to manage partitions.

Your question is unclear, so I will answer both potential questions:

- If you wish to keep both your Ubuntu OS partition and your Windows partition, then from within Ubuntu you may run the "Disks" utility. Type "Disks" into the search field of the Ubuntu menu.

  First select the disk, then select the partition you wish to delete and click the <kbd>-</kbd> symbol below it.
- If you wish to delete the Ubuntu OS partition as well, leaving only the Windows partition, you may boot to Windows and access a similar tool by going control panel->(set view to large icons in the top right)->administrative tools->computer management->disk manager or run `diskmgmt.msc`.

  From here you may select disks, and right click on partitions to delete them.

Be certain you wish to delete a partition, recovering them completely is usually impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Gparted in Ubuntu is a good partition management tool.  I believe you can use it to delete partitions and then resize/enlarge other partitions.  Be very careful though and make sure you've backed up all of your data before you try any of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is [GParted live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php). I imagine you will need to incorporate the free space into the other partitions after you've deleted them. GParted live can merge, delete, create, pretty much all the possible functionality. Better to use the live version than the desktop one. Make sure you get acquainted with it first before you use it, a couple of YouTube tutorials will do the trick and make sure you have another device with you while doing it to look anything up, the built-in browser functionality is extremely limited.